# CSS | Placing div on top of web background

Tags: html, css, background, z-index

I need to place a background image (#foreground) on top of website global background(@wrapper). The problem is that wrapper's background is being displayed on top of foreground's, although wrapper has lower z-index and foreground.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        //website content here
    </div>
    <div id="foreground"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper { 
    width:100%;
    background:url(../img/header/main_bg01.jpg) repeat-x top center, url(../img/header/patternextra.jpg) repeat top center; 
    min-height:1650px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: -2;
}

#foreground {
    background: url(../img/foreground.png) repeat 90% 110%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Tip #1: z-index values only are applied to positioned elements, and your wrapper isn't. Also, try to avoid negative z-indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index doesn't work without position being specified.

Try:

```
#wrapper { 
    width:100%;
    background:url(../img/header/main_bg01.jpg) repeat-x top center, url(../img/header/patternextra.jpg) repeat top center; 
    min-height:1650px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: -2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change z-indexes to positive values:

```
#wrapper { 
    z-index: 1;
}

#foreground {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkokarhu/4y37zkpu/